# Xcode main.storyboard Changed to XML File

Tags: xml, xcode, xcode8, xcode-storyboard

I am in the process of making an app and I found that my main.storyboard file had changed to "navigation" as an XML file and I can't seem to turn it back into a storyboard format. I am not sure how and when it turned to "navigation". After trying to find a solution, I found to right click on the file and select "Open As" and then "Storyboard", but that is not an option. Here are two screenshots:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Rename the file adding the `.storyboard` extension. `MainInterface.storyboard` for instance.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me.